# Oracle get the last date for one month

Tags: sql, oracle

I am not very good with Queries and Database.
I have the the following data table

```
Date        ID  Value
20160601    1   300
20160607    1   301
20160601    2   600
20160607    2   601
20160501    1   250
20160507    1   240
20160501    2   800
20160507    2   801
```

my requirement is to select the last date of a given month for each ID and show the value.
for example, If I choose month 5 the result would be:

```
Date        ID  Value
20160507    1   240
20160507    2   801
```

and so on based on the month the user will enter.

I know it may look simple but I am really stuck and I would appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: The all IDs always exist for all dates - or could IDs 1 and 2 have different max dates within a month? What should happen if they do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the maximum date then select all rows with that date.

```
select * 
from table
where date = (select max(date) from table where date like '201605%')
```

Comment: THANKS !!
IT WORKS NOW

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `date` is an actual date column (as it should be), you can use `extract` to compare the month value, and then the `row_number() over ...` analytic function to get the latest row per `id` value:

```
select date, id, value
  from (select date, id, value,
               row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) as rn
          from tbl
         where extract(month from date) = 5)
 where rn = 1
```

Of course, I assume that your actual date column is called something else, as `date` is a reserved word.

Comment: I am sorry to inform you that the date data is as it is. a NUMBER. so after trying your query Im getting errors

Comment: Based on the answer you accepted, it doesn't look like it's a number either :)